# Code doesn't work in coderbytes but it works in Cloud9

Tags: ruby, cloud9-ide

In Cloud9 I use the following code and it works.

```rb
def LongestWord(sen)
  i = 0
  cha ="&@%*^$!~(){}|?<>"
  new = ""
  while i < sen.length
    i2 = 0
    ch = false
    while i2 < cha.length
      if sen[i] == cha[i2]
        ch = true
      end
      i2 += 1
    end

    if ch == false
      new += sen[i].to_s
    end
    i += 1
  end

  words = new.split(" ")
  longest = ""
  idx = 0
  count = 0
  while idx < words.length
    word = words[idx]

    if word.length > count
      longest = word
      count = word.length
    end
    idx += 1
  end   
  # code goes here
  return longest

end

# keep this function call here 
# to see how to enter arguments in Ruby scroll down   
LongestWord("beautifull word")
```

In Codebytes in the exercise "Longest Word" you have to use the same STDIN in the arguments. It is the same code but changing the argument but it doesn't work:

```rb
def LongestWord(sen)
  i = 0
  cha ="&@%*^$!~(){}|?<>"
  new = ""
  while i < sen.length
    i2 = 0
    ch = false
    while i2 < cha.length
      if sen[i] == cha[i2]
        ch = true
      end
      i2 += 1
    end

    if ch == false
      new += sen[i].to_s
    end
    i += 1
  end

  words = new.split(" ")
  longest = ""
  idx = 0
  count = 0
  while idx < words.length
    word = words[idx]

    if word.length > count
      longest = word
      count = word.length
    end
    idx += 1
  end   
  # code goes here
  return longest

end

# keep this function call here 
# to see how to enter arguments in Ruby scroll down   
LongestWord(STDIN.gets)
```

I think may be something is creating some kind of conflict with the browser. The output shows a lot of numbers. Can some one help me testing the code?. Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coderbyte is running your code on an old version of Ruby - Ruby 1.8.7

In this version of Ruby, using an index into a string like `sen[i]` doesn't return the character at `i`, it returns the numeric ASCII value of that character instead. That's where the numbers are coming from.

To get the code to work on Ruby 1.8.7 you can replace `some_string[i]` with `some_string[i, 1]` - this variation returns the substring of length 1 starting at `i` so is the same as the behaviour of `some_string[i]` in more recent Ruby versions. See the docs [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for more details.